# Как в mysql вывести информацию за прошлую неделю по дате?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Задача реализовать вывод информации за прошлую неделю.
Прошлая неделя считается с понедельника по воскресенье.

Пример, сегодня вторник, мне нужно получить информацию за прошлую неделю с понедельника по воскресенье включительно.

Мой запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ugc_phones WHERE date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND date < CURRENT_DATE
```

У меня есть сомнения в правильности выданных данных. Подскажите, как правильно реализовать ?

Comment: *У меня есть сомнения в правильности выданных данных.* Правильно сомневаетесь. Это не предыдущая неделя, а предыдущие 7 дней. Правильный результат будет исключительно по понедельникам.

Comment: А возможно реализовать как-то, чтобы получать за прошлую неделю ?

Comment: Можно. Составьте выражения для понедельника и для воскресенья предыдущей недели, и используйте. Выражение для понедельника текущей недели я уже давал в одной из предыдущих тем - возьмите его, и просто отнимайте больше дней.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с функцией [YEARWEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek):

```
SELECT SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM ugc_phones 
WHERE YEARWEEK(date) = YEARWEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Comment: @Akina  подскажите, на каких данных будет неверно [фиддла](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a75bd44233216616b8d748c2f0df6b43).

Comment: Точно, перепутал с WeekOfYear().